# Why do pro Zerg players build their Lair at their natural?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

Lately in LotV, I've seen professional Zerg players build their lair at their natural (at least, against Terran) rather than in their main base. Why? Wouldn't the main be a safer choice?

Comment: The main reason is more health. The rest is just speculations and rumors. You want your natural to be more resistant to a frontal attack.

Answer (score 3):

## Safer but not Stronger

According to [this Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/allthingszerg/comments/1k6r9s/lair_at_the_natural_and_not_the_main_why/cbly87y/):

> Most people that lair at the nat in ZvP and ZvT do it because it's easier to defend and less likely to be dropped, which is also why many people don't throw all their tech buildings in the main either. Side benefits are that it also punishes a terran that scans the main instead of the natural.

Comment: I'm going to  think of that from now on, like just putting hatch-tech  structures in the main and upper tech structures in less evident areas

Comment: Yeah your main army is most likely closer to your natural expansion, so it's easier to defend. If you are 100% going mutas, I've seen numerous people put the spire in the main because you can defend against drops easier.

Comment: Hi Pown, again, it seems the majority of this answer was copied from another source, without stating where it's from. As this and your other answer were found at the same time, I'll be lenient again and ask that in future you clearly state where any information is from if you are quoting it word-for-word. In case you missed it, you should also check out our [rules around plagiarism](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and see how to properly reference an answer. Thanks.